# Nomenclature for map such that ordinate y is 1 inside region and 0 enywhere else

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the common name to the map below:

$$
y = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
1,  & \mbox{for abcisse } x \in R  \\ 
0,  & \mbox{for abcisse } x \in X-R
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I know delta function $\delta(x)$, which has a low measure on abcisse space, i.e., only for geometrical place $x=0$.

Comment: Can you precise the domain and codomain of your map? This is not clear in your question.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, this is the answer I look for. Do you mind posting it as the desired answer?

Comment: Sure. I will delete to spare some server memory. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any set $X$ and subset $A\subseteq X,$ the map
$$\mathbf{1}_A \colon X \to \{ 0, 1 \},\qquad x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1 ~&\text{ if }~ x \in A, \\
0 ~&\text{ if }~ x \notin A
\end{cases}$$
is called the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A.$

Comment: It looked like a FAQ but I did not succeed in finding a duplicate.

Comment: You are formal. I like it. Thank you for the beautiful answer. France is famous for its mathematical education.